# Как получить список треков пользователя через библиотеку vk_api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Авторизация проходит нормально

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.audio import VkAudio

def main():
    user_id = 123456789
    login, password = 'login', 'password'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
    vk_session.auth()

    vkaudio = VkAudio(vk_session)
    tracks = vkaudio.get(user_id)

    print(tracks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Но метод get падает с ошибкой

```
ValueError: Could not find root el for audio
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/519302/

Comment: @Иван, Спасибо. годная статья )